# How to extend my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.xml; do
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep "sample_freq" "{}" \;
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep "sensor_sernum" "{}" \;
done
```

Works perfect for one folder

```
      <sample_freq>131072</sample_freq>
        <sample_freq>131072</sample_freq>
        <sample_freq>131072</sample_freq>
        <sample_freq>131072</sample_freq>
        <sample_freq>131072</sample_freq>
        <sensor_sernum>0</sensor_sernum>
        <sensor_sernum>0</sensor_sernum>
        <sensor_sernum>255</sensor_sernum>
        <sensor_sernum>237</sensor_sernum>
```

But the problem is that I have seven folders in directory,each of them has one xml file.Is it possible to extend my script,so that it enters all seven folders and gets the information from each off them?
Content of my directory
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/Documents/magnetotellurics/MT8$ ls
EDI´s                     meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28  meas_2015-06-29_19-26-

```
58  meas_2015-06-29_19-47-58  mys.sh   n.sh
meas_2015-06-29_19-03-00  meas_2015-06-29_19-22-58  meas_2015-06-29_19-30-58  meas_2015-06-29_20-39-58
```

I have tried what choroba adviced me to do

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*; do                                                                                      
    grep 'sample_freq'   "$file"
    grep 'sensor_sernum' "$file"
done
```

But

```
grep: ./EDI´s: Is a directory
grep: ./EDI´s: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-03-00: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-03-00: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-22-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-22-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-26-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-26-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-30-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-30-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-47-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_19-47-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_20-39-58: Is a directory
grep: ./meas_2015-06-29_20-39-58: Is a directory
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep "sample_freq" "{}" \;
    grep 'sample_freq'   "$file"
    grep 'sensor_sernum' "$file"
    grep 'sample_freq'   "$file"
    grep 'sensor_sernum' "$file"
```

Comment: You don't use the variable $file anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `for` loop at all.

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep "sample_freq" "{}" \; -exec grep "sensor_sernum" "{}" \;
```

Comment: Yes,works exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: @MikiBelavista - It may seem to work exactly the way you want but for the record, the second `grep`  is executed only if there's at least one match found in the file by the first `grep`. It doesn't look like that's what you want (at least not after reading your question twice). Anyway, unless the order of lines in the output matters, using two `exec`s (hence two `grep`s) is pointless as you can simply run `grep 'sample_freq\|sensor_sernum'`

Answer (score 0):

No `find` needed here, just use the $file variable, but expand the wildcard that includes the path:

```
for file in folder*/*.xml ; do                                                                                       # */ fix SE highlighting bug
    grep 'sample_freq'   "$file"
    grep 'sensor_sernum' "$file"
done
```

Comment: @How to expand the wildcard?

Comment: @MikiBelavista: The shell does it for you if the wildcard isn't quoted.